# Sylius UI flag icon not showing

Tags: sylius

In twig template
I use sylius flags macro:

```
{% import '@SyliusUi/Macro/flags.html.twig' as syliusUiFlags %}
{{ syliusUiFlags.fromLocaleCode(locale.code) }}
```

what returns me what i'd expected.
`locale` is instance of `Sylius\Component\Locale\Model\Locale`

But for ukrainian locale `locale.code` is "uk", and in style.css flag icon defined as `i.flag.ua` and `i.flag.ukraine`.
So, flag `i.flag.uk` is not shown with this rules: `background: url(themes/default/assets/images/flags.png) no-repeat -108px -1976px;`

For now i see one solution - adding custom css with

```
i.flag.uk:before { background-position:-72px -1872px !important; }
```

How to fix this specific issue? Without using custom css rule or adding something like this:

```
{% if locale.code == 'uk' %}
    {% set localeCode = 'ua' %}
{% else %}
    {% set localeCode = locale.code %}
{% endif %}
syliusUiFlags.fromLocaleCode(localeCode)
```

Comment: I realized that this is due to Semantic UI, not Sylius.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried on actual Sylius demo on showing an order, it uses `ua`, so you're right there used not correct code according to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes). The fastest way is to use twig code which described above, but correct way is fixing input (received) data, for example with modifying record in DB in table `sylius_locale` from `ua` to `uk`, but it can cause problem in other website places.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I keep it in my mind.
I can't change locale in db, because it is needed as a [plugin](https://github.com/yaroslavche/sylius-translation-plugin), which simply works with existing locales, but doesn't change them .
PS. and why else is redundant? The localeCode is defined inside if and is not available in the setFromLocale method if localeCode! = 'uk'. Or I'm wrong? I'm new to the twig

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely correct, I missed that you declaring this variable in `if` scope)) I will edit my message above for misconfusing others